# USB C 3.1 Mini PC capable of running Linux

Tags: usb, power-supply, mini-pc, nuc, usb-c

I have an MBP for work. I want to have a dedicated development environment for private projects to not mess up my work setup. Also, I wanna run Linux (just Ubuntu something).

The MBP is currently connected via USB C 3.1 to a display featuring a USB hub providing mouse and keyboard connectivity. The nice thing here is, of course, that I only need to connect one single USB C cable to have these things:

- video signal
- power supply
- connection to keyboard and mouse via USB hub

So, in a sense, it replaces a docking station.

First I thought about just buying a Dell XPS 13. I mean it runs Linux natively and has USB C 3.1. So I could just go ahead and switch between the MBP and the Dell.

Then I thought, why would I even need a laptop. I have an older notebook at home and a mini PC would be just enough.

### TL;DR

Long story short, is there a mini PC (up to 900 Euro) out there with the following specs:

**Mandatory**:

- Video signal via USB C 3.1 DP (need to handle QHD 60Hz)
- Able to run Ubuntu out of the box
- Decent hardware for smooth development
- Available for EU (shipment and power supply)
- Wifi and Bluetooth

**Kinda mandatory**, but not a deal-breaker "in case":

- Power supply via USB C

**Nice to have**, but optional:

- VESA mountable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple [Intel NUCs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/boards-kits/nuc/nuc-family-overview.html?) meet all those specifications, except for the power supply by USB-C (they all include their own power supply). Intel themselves confirms [QHD compatibility](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D70P0000068WtMSAU/nuc6cayh-to-qhd-monitor?language=en_US) on at least one model.